# Adding free O365 to free (dev) Azure tenant

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, office365, single-sign-on

Is there any **free** way to add a Office 365 tenant to a free Azure AD tenant. I already have the free Azure tenant which I use quite heavily for coding applications connecting to various Azure resources and also for testing SSO/SAML/OpenID auth in Apps before moving them to the pre-production stage but I now have a situation whereby the client want to connect to Azure resources (already covered) and also to Exchange Online.

Is there any way I can sign up (for free) to Office 365 and have this connected to my current AzureAD tenant?

when i try to sign up using the link here:
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/dev-program

I am informed that the domain (used in my Azure tenant) is already used and cannot progress any further

Comment: You need to have a custom domain name.

Comment: Having to buy a custom domain kind of defeats the "Free" idea. Is this the only way?